# Writing queries to mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a very quick question. Probably it has an easy answer. I have to following query which works:

```
$query = "UPDATE ".$db['postRecordTableName']." SET Posted = 1";
```

I know what the query is doing and I also know php. However, there is one thing that I am not really sure about. Why do we need concatenation to write a query from php. Even thought my query is working, I can not see the reason.  I would really appreciate if anyone answer this question. Thank you in advanced

Comment: Well technically you don't need it and *could* do `UPDATE {$db['postRecordTableName']} SET Posted = 1`. Not sure why it's a concern though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use PHP's [**Complex Curly Syntax**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) and not have to concatenate

```
 $query = "UPDATE {$db['postRecordTableName']} SET Posted = 1";
```

Note:

> This isn't called complex because the syntax is complex, but because it allows for the use of complex expressions.

Comment: Yeah I am just trying to understand the reason. This is my first project where I combined both, I just want to make sure I know what I am doing

Comment: PHP easily picks up variable values from within double quoted strings. If your variable was not an array you could even do the same without curly braces but this is the proper way in such a case. Single quoted strings will not be interpolated and you won't get any variable's value in there.

Comment: I got it now, thank you . I was just looking for a good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP's **[sprintf()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)**

You can so this without concatenation:

```
$query = sprintf("UPDATE %s SET Posted = 1",$db['postRecordTableName']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this:

```
<?php
  $table = $db['postRecordTableName'];
  $query = "UPDATE $table SET Posted = 1";
?>
```

You don't need concatenation to write a query.

you need it because it is sometimes required, depending on how you create the query string.